# Typescript/Javascript array of Object of array to push

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

`myArray: any[] = [];`

Through Get API I am getting response which I am pushing to my already define empty array("myArray"), now "myArray" look like this

```
myArray = [
    X[    0:{Object1},  #1
          1:{Object2},  #2
          2:{Object3}   #3
     ], 
    Y[    0:{Object4},  #4
          1:{Object5},  #5
          2:{Object6}   #6
     ],  
    Z[    0:{Object7},  #7
          1:{Object8},  #8
          2:{Object9}   #9
     ] 
           ];
```

Now I have declared a new empty array,

```
xyzArray: any[] = [];
```

I want to push all Object i.e. Object 1 to 9 to myNewArray. How can I achieve this? I want something like this:

```
xyzArray = [     0:{Object1},   #1
                 1:{Object2},   #2
                 2:{Object3},   #3
                 3:{Object4},   #4
                 4:{Object5},   #5
                 5:{Object6},   #6
                 6:{Object7},   #7
                 7:{Object8},   #8
                 8:{Object9}    #9
        ];
```

Comment: That depends on what exactly are you trying to do, do you need a cloned elements, or just references etc. Some proper example code would ease up helping..

Comment: None of your code is valid JavaScript. Please fix that to give us a clear idea of what you need, and provide an attempt of your own.

Comment: please share the problem code snippets, like you can use jsfiddle.net

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL JSFiddle is less desirable. There’s the built-in Stack Snippet tool here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm accustomed to use jsfiddle but you said it is true. @Xufox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b) in JS.

```js
var arr =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

var newArr = arr.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b));

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

For e.g.
you have below array

```
var r = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
```

Then you can merge all elements from 1-9 by looping over all elements of `r`. Like below:

```
var t = []; for (a of r) { for (b of a) { t.push(b); }}
```

```js
var r = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
var t = []; for (a of r) { for (b of a) { t.push(b); }}
console.log(t);
```